# Extjs4 - How to load check radiogroup from form.load

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I have a form include a radiogroup like

```
{
 xtype: 'radiogroup',
        fieldLabel: 'group',
        name: 'a',
        items: [{
            boxLabel: '1',
            name: 'a',
            inputValue: '1'
        }, {
            boxLabel: '2',
            name: 'a',
            inputValue: '2',

        }, {
            boxLabel: '3',
            name: 'a',
            inputValue: '3'
        }]
    }
```

i using

```
form.load({         
     url: 'example.php',
....});
```

my json look like

```
{
    success:true ,
    data : {
       a:'2'    
    }
}
```

But nothing work. How to fix that thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the name attribute on the radiogroup. It shouldn't be there at all or you can name it something else.

```
    xtype: 'radiogroup',
    fieldLabel: 'group',
    name: 'a'  <--- REMOVE
```

Here is your code sample in a fiddle. Instead of load() method on form i am using setValues method on the FormBasic becuase i don't have a server to load data from. But it works in the same way. 
http://jsfiddle.net/dbrin/JMmHz/

Essentially the problem is that it is looking for the first input element to match the name of the input value and is finding the radiogroup instead of the individual radio.

Comment: i remove that on my code but nothing, that's still not working :(

Comment: did you see my fiddle? from the code you provided that was the problem. DO you have more code that may be a problem too?

Comment: Thanks @dbrin b/c i have more like id='a' and i just change it and now, working thank u :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a callback method to the call, like this:

```
form.load({
    url: 'example.php', 
    success: function(response, options) {
      form.setValues(Ext.decode(response.data));
    }
});
```

Comment: i think success function like `success:function(form, action){form.setValues(action.result.data);}` but that's not working?